# align bytearray to be 16 bit compatible

Tags: python, arrays, struct, alignment

There is a need for storing and retrieving some data which can be string formatted in a known way. But the data needs to be 16 bit aligned as the storing device doesn't support it. In order to store the data efficiently, I am packing the data in a known format using struct pack. But how should I align the data to be 16 bit so that retrieving and storing doesn't screw up the data?
for eg.

```
data = [12,b'c', 100009, b"string", 3.45]

stringformat of data = "icl6sd"

packed data =b'\x0c\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00\xa9\x86\x01
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00string\x00\x00\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\x0b@'
```

How do I convert this data to be 16 bit aligned?

Answer (score 0):

`struct.pack` knows all about C-compiler byte-alignment and will add packing bytes to your data without being asked. That is why your structure is 32 bytes long, even though your data calls for 4 + 1 + 4 + 6 + 8 (=23) bytes of of data. Look closely and you will see (for example) that `string` has been padded out on the right with an extra null byte so that the double will occupy the last 8 bytes of the structure. So I'm not sure I'm convinced that the alignment is wrong.

You *can* take charge of the padding yourself (format `x`) but I suggest that `struct.pack` knows exactly what it is doing.

If your packed data isn't being interpreted as you expect, it is *much* more likely that there is a problem with the struct specification or that the byte order is not what you expect.